# What if I realize I should have committed an edit five commits ago?

Tags: git, debugging, commit

This is a common problem for me. I make five or so commits then find that some debug code that became irrelevant or junk code from a prior used algorithm stays around. Amending them to HEAD doesn't always make sense and making a new commit for a one-line late change feels disorderly.

The solutions I know of include the above and checking out the previous commit, branching, editing and merging again. This works fine, but I wonder if either a more idiomatic or elegant solution exists.

Comment: If you already have push the changes to somewhere you can't really take them back and you'll have to live with them. Even if that means one-line changes.

Comment: "making a new commit for a one-line late change feels disorderly" -- My advice: don't worry about that.

Comment: That usually doesn't matter. Most of the time, such issues only happening during one session. I rarely push.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use interactive rebase to go back and edit a specific commit, as long as rewriting history is okay (basically, as long as you haven't shared the commits with anyone else/the public).

To do so, first find the hash of the commit you want to edit. Then, tell Git to do an interactive rebase from the commit before it:

```
git rebase -i <SHA>~1
```

The `~1` is important - it tells Git to reference the commit before the SHA you specified.

This will bring up an editor with a line for each of your commits starting with the one you want to edit. Change the `pick` for that commit to `edit`, then save and quit out of the editor.

Git will apply that commit, and then pause. You can then edit the files to remove the debug code, `git add` them, and `git commit --amend` to edit the commit.

Afterwards, use `git rebase --continue` to apply the other commits in order, ending up back where you started (but with a new set of commits that doesn't have your debugging code).

Answer (score 1):

You can use rebase if you haven't pushed or been pulled from yet.

[Squashing with rebase](http://gitready.com/advanced/2009/02/10/squashing-commits-with-rebase.html)

Comment: As a side note, I do this a lot myself and this neatly cleans up the commit log.